# Line chart using nvd3

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm new to this d3 and nvd3.I'm trying to build a multi line chart using nvd3 and i have got 2 issues

1) the x axis doesn't seem to show the right values for hour and minutes as in json data which has date in standard utc format.

2) when i put the the first value as non-zero for both memory and cpu it scales down to negative y axis and looks weird.

Ty for the help.   [here is the plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/HOugasn8rHNTkpSmf828?p=preview)

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
var chart = nv.models.cumulativeLineChart()
    .x(function(d) {
        console.log(d.time)
        return d.time
    })

.y(function(d) {
    console.log(d.value)
    return d.value
})
    .color(["#FF0000", "#000000"])
    .height(210)
    .width(420)
    .useInteractiveGuideline(false)
    .showControls(false)
    .forceY(0)

;


chart.xAxis
    .tickFormat(function(d) {
        return d3.time.format('%H:%M')(new Date(d))
    });
 chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.1'));
d3.select('nv-indexLine').fill("black");
d3.select('#chart svg')
    .datum(formattedData)
    .call(chart);

nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

chart.lines.interactive(false);

return chart;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One change make your function like this for return x values it should return a Date object.

So instead of doing this

```
.x(function(d) {
    console.log(d.time)
    return d.time
})
```

Do like this to return Date object

```
.x(function(d) {
            console.log(d.time)
            return new Date(d.time)
        })
```

working code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/2aLQvNi5xuxcXjx1338g?p=preview)

Comment: tnx Cyril this is fine.But for any non-zero first  value from json it doesnt show what it shoud

Comment: I dont see anything negative http://www.clipular.com/c/5201356112003072.png?k=wRztx1RefEHHu8-gzhsEFNancrQ please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Tats probably because of forceY(0).. Removing tat nd it shows up even for positive val